# Regex any characters except one specific, with break line PHP

Tags: php, regex

I would like to build a regex that grep all characters between [[xxx]], with new line.

```
[[dgghr]]
[[dfgdfgfd
dgfsdgdg]]

/\[\[([\s\S]+)\]\]/s
```

But this regex grep :

```
"df]]
[[df 
d
gfdg"
```

I would like :

```
"dgghr" and "dfgdfgfd
    dgfsdgdg"
```

I tried to exclude "]" character, without success :(
Thank you for all.
G.

### Edit

I've just finded! Here the solution : 
String :

```
[[dgghr]]
[[dfgdfgfd
dgfsdgdg]]
```

Regex :

```
/\[\[([\s\S][^\]]+)\]\]/s
```

Output :

```
array('dgghr', 'dfgdfgfd\ndgfsdgdg')
```

Thank you MariaDeleva and splash58
G.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? And what should be matched and what shouldn't be matched?

Comment: add `m` modifier to search im multy-line mode - https://regex101.com/r/jX4aC9/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude a character, use a negated class : `[^x]` matches any character but `x`. Since `]` has a special meaning in character classes, you have to escape it : `[^\]]`

Now simply excluding `]` could give you undesirable results if the text bewteen double brackets can contain brackets : `\[\[[^\]]*\]\]` wouldn't match `[[this]test]]`.

I believe the only problem with your regex is that it is greedy : it will match as much as it can, rather than stopping to the first match, so the `[\S\s]` class will match closing brackets as long as there are others that can be matched by `\]\]` later.
So what I propose is to make your `[\S\s]+` part lazy/non-greedy, as in the following :

```
/\[\[([\s\S]+?)\]\]/s
```

You can try it [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tV0hN5/1).

Comment: Thank you Aaron, it's perfect! I've edited my post with another regex that matches what I needed.

Comment: @user5551022 careful though, my second point still stands : if you've got a single closing bracket in your bracketed data the whole segment won't match